# How to analyze/visualize twitter network of specific area?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, social-networking, network-analysis

I want to analyze or visualize overall twitter network of specific area(country or state). 
I know There are ways to analyze or visualize network of specific people through the method of who he/she is following and who are following back but i want to analyze overall twitter network of specific area.

**Background Research:**
There are ways to visualize your twitter network like discussed in this article:
http://allthingsgraphed.com/2014/11/02/twitter-friends-network/

Moreover, you can also generate a network graph of twitter followers using python and networkX:
http://mark-kay.net/2014/08/15/network-graph-of-twitter-followers/
There are also tools like Tweepsmap(http://tweepsmap.com/partners/Garin) available to get your twitter network of specific area

But still the question is how to analyze/visualize overall twitter network of specific area ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hello. Share some code with us or share some knowledge on what you have investigated / research on exactly.

Comment: There are ways to visualize your twitter network like discussed in this article:
http://allthingsgraphed.com/2014/11/02/twitter-friends-network/

Moreover, you can also generate a network graph of twitter followers using python and networkX:
http://mark-kay.net/2014/08/15/network-graph-of-twitter-followers/

There are also tools like Tweepsmap(http://tweepsmap.com/partners/Garin) available to get your twitter network of specific area  

But still the question is how to analyze/visualize overall twitter network of specific area ?